# Hide and Show Nested Elements In DOM

Tags: jquery

I am having below markup where I want to hide/show the divs as per the classes provided. Below is my markup which is somewhere in DOM. Can you please provide the way to do so. There is tabpanel where the content is available and on the basis of id myId1 or myId2, appropriate div of tabpanel should hide and show.

```
 <div id="tabs">
    <div class="hader-tabing">
       <nav>
          <div id="nav-tab">
             <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li><a href="#myId1"></li>
                <li><a href="#myId2"></li>
             </ul>
          </div>
       </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- tabs start  -->
    <div class="tab-content">
       <!-- part 1 Will execute 2 times as  per filters-->
       <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="myId1">
          <div class="row">
             <div class="col-xs-5ths ">
                <div class="dark-box-outer">
                   <div class="top-light-text-box">
                      <div class="inner-tab-box ">
                         <div class="tab-content">
                            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane myId1  " >
                               //content
                            </div>
                            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane myId1  ">
                               // content
                            </div>
                            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane myId2 ">
                              // content
                            </div>
                            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane myId2 ">
                              // content
                            </div>
                            ... n times
                         </div>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="top-light-text-box">
                      // similar type of markup as above

                    </div>
                   <div class="top-light-text-box">
                         // similar type of markup as above
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-xs-5ths ">
                // content
             </div>
             ... n times
          </div>
        </div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="myId2">
          // same markup will repeated as above
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where is the Javascript? The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this...using jquery,

```js
$('ul.nav.nav-tabs>li>a').click(function(){
  var curtab = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
  $('.tab-content .tab-pane').each(function(){
    var tabid = this.className;
    if(tabid.indexOf(curtab) > -1){
      $(this).siblings().hide();
      $(this).show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">
    <div class="hader-tabing">
       <nav>
          <div id="nav-tab">
             <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li><a href="#myId1">ID1</li>
                <li><a href="#myId2">ID2</li>
             </ul>
          </div>
       </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- tabs start  -->
    <div class="tab-content">
       <!-- part 1 Will execute 2 times as  per filters-->
       <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="myId1">
          <div class="row">
             <div class="col-xs-5ths ">
                <div class="dark-box-outer">
                   <div class="top-light-text-box">
                      <div class="inner-tab-box ">
                         <div class="tab-content">
                            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane myId1  " >
                               //content ID1
                            </div>
                            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane myId1  ">
                               // content ID1
                            </div>
                            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane myId2 ">
                              // content ID2
                            </div>
                            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane myId2 ">
                              // content ID2
                            </div>
                            ... n times
                         </div>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="top-light-text-box">
                      // similar type of markup as above

                    </div>
                   <div class="top-light-text-box">
                         // similar type of markup as above
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-xs-5ths ">
                // content
             </div>
             ... n times
          </div>
        </div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="myId2">
          <div class="row">
             <div class="col-xs-5ths ">
                <div class="dark-box-outer">
                   <div class="top-light-text-box">
                      <div class="inner-tab-box ">
                         <div class="tab-content">
                            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane myId1  " >
                               //content ID1
                            </div>
                            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane myId1  ">
                               // content ID1
                            </div>
                            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane myId2 ">
                              // content ID2
                            </div>
                            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane myId2 ">
                              // content ID2
                            </div>
                            ... n times
                         </div>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="top-light-text-box">
                      // similar type of markup as above

                    </div>
                   <div class="top-light-text-box">
                         // similar type of markup as above
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-xs-5ths ">
                // content
             </div>
             ... n times
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```